# Sample text for common scripts

Tags: unicode, localization, fonts, internationalization

The Windows font chooser dialog displays different text according to the selected 'Script' (corresponding to legacy [Windows code pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#Windows_.28ANSI.29_code_pages), I think). I want to preview fonts that support scripts not listed there, however, and I was wondering if there is a resource of short (~8-12 characters) strings useful for this purpose.

Here's what I've got so far, based on the preview text from the Windows font chooser:

- Latin: AaBbYyZz
- Greek: AaBbΑαΒβ
- Cyrillic: AaBbБбФф
- Hebrew: AaBbנסשת
- Arabic: AaBbابجدهوز
- Thai: AaBbอักษรไทย
- Korean: 가나다AaBbYyZz
- Japanese: Aaあぁアァ亜宇
- Chinese: 中文字型範例
- Devanagari: माता
- Gurmukhi: ਮਾਤਾ
- Gujarati: માતા
- Tamil: அம்மா
- Telugu: అమ్మ
- Kannada: ಅಮ್ಮ

The Chinese text is from the Traditional Chinese preview text in the font chooser dialog - I'd like text that's good for simplified and traditional fonts, so I'm not sure about this one.

The six South Asian scripts at the end of the list all use the word 'mother', which seems a bit strange, but I'll use the same pattern for Malayalam:

- Malayalam: അമ്മ

In [Bengali](http://bn.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BE), however, 'mother' is apparently only two characters long (মা), so I'd prefer to find something else for that language.

I'm missing sample text for the following languages/scripts:

- Armenian: ?
- Bengali: ?
- Oriya: ?
- Lao: ?
- Tibetan: ?
- Georgian: ?

Comment: Is your question just for someone to look up some sample text for those scripts?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know if there's a commonly used string for each.

Comment: Well seems a bit off topic for stackoverflow, it's probably not hard to look up some text in wikipedia or something

Comment: I figured it's relevant as an internationalisation issue. I can easily grab text off Wikipedia, but I'm looking for sample text in the same style as the others.